# Failure to Initialize SUSI API dll

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I'm attempting to use the SUSI api dll that was provided to me. The first step according to their documentation is to call SusiLibInitialize. When calling it I seem to only get the failure result from the function when I'm expected to get SUSI_STATUS_INITIALIZED as the result.

I do not have much experience with c++ dlls however several other articles and posts seems to do it as down below. I've also tried passing the name of the external function in the function declaration. Am I calling it incorrectly or could this be a issue with the DLL? The application they provided (closed sourced) is able to use it correctly.

```pascal
const
  SUSI_DLL = 'Susi4.dll';
  SUSI_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED = $FFFFFFFF;
  SUSI_STATUS_INITIALIZED = $FFFFFFFE;
  SUSI_STATUS_SUCCESS = $0;

function SusiLibInitialize: UInt32; stdcall; external SUSI_DLL;

{$R *.fmx}

procedure TForm1.btnTestClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  var
  result := SusiLibInitialize;

  if result = SUSI_STATUS_INITIALIZED then
    ShowMessage('Init')
  else if result = SUSI_STATUS_SUCCESS then
    ShowMessage('Success')
  else if result = SUSI_STATUS_NOT_INITIALIZED then
    ShowMessage('Failure');
end;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You might find this useful: http://www.rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-dlls.html

Comment: Amazing. This actually explains a lot more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before posting the question I never thought that it might be a hardware requirement. After posting the question I suddenly had the idea to run it on the machine itself it works there.